# Angular NgFor Issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to display the list of the object having id and name using NgFor directive but i am getting below error :

**Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

Below are the codes files for reference .

**`heroes.component.ts:**

This file has heroes object declared.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  import { Hero } from '../hero';

  import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-heroes',
    templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
  })

  export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {   
    heroes = HEROES;
  }
```

**heroes.component.html:**

This is the file where I am using NgFor in

tag .

```
 <ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
     <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**mock-heroes.ts:**

This files contains the constant object of the heroes that i want to be displayed on UI.

```
  import {Hero} from './hero';    
  export const HEROES: Hero[] ={        
    {id:11 , name:'Mr. Nice'},
    {id:12 , name:'Narco'},
    {id:13 , name:'Bombasto'}
  };
```

Can you please help me here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error denotes

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'

Your Heroes should be an array instead of object. change it as,

```
const HEROES: Hero[] =[
     {id:11 , name:'Mr. Nice'},
     {id:12 , name:'Narco'},
     {id:13 , name:'Bombasto'}
];
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mphn97?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan . It is working now after the change as suggested by you .

Answer (score 2):

ngFor doesn't support object  try this below :

```
export const HEROES: Hero[] =[

     {id:11 , name:'Mr. Nice'},
     {id:12 , name:'Narco'},
     {id:13 , name:'Bombasto'}
];
```

Comment: Hey Klodian Thanks a lot for the help . It worked fine after making correction suggested by you.

Answer (score 1):

you should define HEROES as an array, with `[ ]` instead of `{ }` as the outer enclosing braces :

```
[
  { ... },
  { ... },
]
```

instead of

```
{
  { ... },
  { ... },
}
```

Comment: Hi Pac0 Thanks for your answer and time . It is working now without any issues .